# Semantic-UI Modal won't re-open after an AJAX Update Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I update a record's table row with AJAX. I cannot re-open the modal for semantic-ui, but when I click the open modal button before I update the record - It does so without issue. Has anyone experienced this? How can I get the modal to re-initialize after an AJAX update in Rails? The strange part is that the id is still set for the button, it just doesn't open the modal after updating the record.

**chart_records_controller.rb**

```
def update

respond_to |format|
   if @chart_record.update(chart_record_params)
   format.js {}
 else
  format.js {}
 end
end
```

**update.js.erb**

```
document.getElementById('<%= dom_id(@chart_record, 'inline_form') %>').remove()
document.getElementById('<%= dom_id(@chart_record, 'inline_form') %>').innerHTML = "<%= j render @chart_record %>"
document.getElementById('<%= dom_id(@chart_record, 'inline_form') %>').style.display = 'table-row'
```

**_chart_record.html.erb**

```
<div class="divTableCell"><%= link_to chart_record.date %></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><%= link_to chart_record.username %></div>
<div class="divTableCell">
 <button class="ui icon button" id="chart_record_comment_btn_<%= chart_record.id">
</button>

<div class="ui modal chart_record_comment_modal_<%= chart_record.id %>">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
 <div class="p-3">
   <%= simple_form_for(chart_record, url: update_comment_for_chart_record(id: chart_record.id), method: :post, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :comment_body, as: :text, label: "Comment" %>   
  <%= f.submit 'Update Comment', class: 'ui button' %>
<% end %>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
 // only works before record is updated inline.
 $('#chart_record_btn_<%= chart_record.id' %>').click(function() {
    $('ui.modal.chart_record_comment_modal_<%= chart_record.id %>').modal('show')
  });
</script>
```

Comment: after run update, open the browser console and run `$('ui.modal.chart_record_comment_modal_<%= chart_record.id %>').modal('show')` to verify if it still works. Replace `<%= chart_record.id %>` with real specify id because it browser console it run as pure javascript.

Comment: I will try, shortly. But, its weird that the modal no longer works after changes are made with AJAX.

Comment: I'm getting jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn,init(1)] length: 0 _proto_: Object(0)

Comment: It worked after putting $('ui.modal.chart_record_comment_modal)... in the onclick="" parameter for the button itself.

Comment: trying add `$('ui.modal.chart_record_comment_modal_<%= chart_record.id %>').modal('show')` into you update js file

Answer (score 0):

I simply called the modal with the onclick parameter for the button itself. I think the update forced the DOM into a not ready state. It seems hacky, but there's no other way to get the JS to re-initialize the modal.

```
<button type="button" onclick="$('ui.modal.chart_record_comment_modal_<%= chart_record.id %>').modal('show')"><i class="icon comment outline"></i></button>
```